# mailgun, mailing lists, get members with params

Tags: ruby, email, rest-client, mailgun, mailing-list

I can add email to mailgun mailing list using the following resource:

POST /lists/your_mailing_list_name/members

You can create member with additional vars(attributes) as it is said in docs. (https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-mailinglists.html#mailing-lists).

But I can't figure out how can I get members of lists using this attributes filters. Is it possible? I didn't find any info in docs about that. Maybe somebody worked with that and can help me. If it is not possible, why do we need those vars attributes?

I'm using ruby and RestClient for calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is not possible right now. I've contact mailgun support and they told me about that.